# Questions on structural eng drawing for egress window

Tags: structural-engineering

I am installing an egress window in my basement to make it a legal bedroom. I am going to be doing most of the work myself (outside of cutting the concrete) but doing it by the book (permits, inspections, etc). I hired a structural engineer to do the drawings. I will try to follow his drawings to the T, but there are a few things I am unclear on, highlighted in the drawing.

1. Did the engineer intentionally not include threaded rod for the header and I'm not seeing how it's secured? Or was that an oversight?
2. I don't fully understand the engineer's vision for securing the threaded rods to the vertical structural supports.
3. I have no idea what the symbol means where the vertical support and the header meet (maybe that will answer question #2?)

[image: Structural Engineer's Drawings]

Comment: I deleted my comment because it no longer serves a purpose ... it was just clutter

Comment: the top plate is probably nailed to the concrete ... the symbol looks like a nail ... the sides are bolted on, because they have to support hinges

Comment: maybe https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions is a more suitable place for this ... it has people that read blueprints as part of their job

Comment: I plan to do that too. I didn't realize there was a limit of 1 post per 40 minutes across all of stack exchange.So, I am waiting for that 40 minutes to lapse. :)

Comment: The top plate typically just sits on the side plates. It's held down by mortar and the weight of the building. I /think/ that notation means it is welded in place. Also, you don't torque the wall-plates into place (you don't torque a door jam into place). The thread is to engage with the adhesive.

Comment: I would be opposed to putting vertical rods where you drew them because they could crack the concrete during bending of the stop HSS. Better to let the top HSS do its job and deflect slightly. If you run rod up into the concrete, it will induce shear forces along those rods, and that shear will be resisted by the concrete, which could then crack. So don't do that. The side rods aren't the same issue because there isn't any bending of the vertical HSS. They're just there for stability so that you don't have the concrete migrate away from frame during weather cycling.

Comment: @Rick - Thanks a lot. That makes sense to me. Appreciate the explanation of the difference between the two dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As david mentioned, the symbol has to do with a weld.  It means weld all around (the little circle) and groove should be square on the side pointed by the arrow. Where the arrow points could be a little clearer, but the intent there should basically be to preserve the surface of the side bars (rather than cutting into them for space for the weld material) to bear the load from the top.
There are various weld symbol tables online such as https://www.studiesaddict.com/2019/10/welding-symbols-their-description.html?m=1

Since the sides are welded to the top as one up-side down U, there is no need for rods in the top.

My concern would be heat from welding affecting the epoxy (I would have gone for inserts in the side bars making a threaded install of the rod into the side bars as they're stainless).  At the same time, you have to consider accessibility for your welder since it is a retrofit. It appears the designer favored accessibility mentioning the adhesive prior to the weld.